# WCF IDispatchMessageInspector To Pass Object Instance To Service Context

Tags: wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

In my WCF Service. I have GetCustomerInfo Service

I am intercepting WCF Message in AfterReceiveRequest Method. 
In AfterReceiveRequest i am creating an object instance of myClass which i want to use it in GetCustomerInfo service.

I do not want to use static class, data can get cross pollinated.

Can any one please help me or advise me best way to do this.